# Android SDK and AVD manager will not run from Eclipse after upgrade to SDK 5 and ADT 0.9.6

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

Using Windows 7, 64 bit system. Prior to upgrade I was able to run "Android SDK and AVD manager" from Eclipse via a tool bar icon and menu option, both of which still exist. However now nothing happens when I try to run the manager.

As a result I can't start an emulator from within Eclipse. When I use Eclipse to run an Android app, the first emulator I installed is automatically started.

Using Windows Explorer, I can still run the manager from the SDK directory in which the update was applied (the update didn't change the location of the SDK).  If I run the manager and start multiple emulators and then Run an app from Eclipse, it sees the emulators and allows me to choose one as before. This is a satisfactory work-around, but it would be nice if the manager were fully integrated into Eclipse as it was before.

Comment: Upgrade both ADT and Eclipse.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have. 
Eclipse is build 20100218-1602.
Eclipse Platform 3.5.2.M20100211-1343
Android Development Tools 0.9.6.v201002051504-24846

Selecting Help/Check for Updates in Eclipse comes back with "Nothing to update".
 
SDK shows "Revision 5" on the SDK Setup "About" window.
SDK Setup shows no packages to install

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. I tried uninstalling the plugins and reinstalling them with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Now on the official Android website, Android provide SDK package which include the eclipse and   sdk package. Try that [one](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).